# Maximum and minimum value

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, optimization

$f(x)=2x+7$ has absolute max value at $x=3$, true or false?

The question is wrong, right? Because he should mention an interval?

Comment: That is correct, i.e., the statement is false and your analysis is correct.

Comment: The statement would be true if the domain was the interval $[a,3]$ with $3>a>-10$.

Comment: It's faster to note that $f(4)>f(3)$, and not worry about whether an interval was specified. :)

Comment: I don't think "absolute max value" means the maximum of $|f(x)|$, but that it is not just a local maximum. @almagest

Comment: @almagest, why $-10$?